# How to trigger a function in jquery when using Constructor pattern and prototypes for plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

The problem is as below (critics appreciated):
I am writing a jquery plugin as in the sample code below:

```
;(function($, document, window, undefined) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).data('my', new MyPlugin(params));
        }
    }

    function MyPlugin(params) {
        // do something
    }

    MyPlugin.prototype = {
        init: function() { ... },
        update: function() { ... }
    }

})(jQuery, document, window);
```

Now I wish to call **update function in MyPlugin's prototype**, say, on $(window).onresize.
If that is possible, please someone explain (workaround also welcome). Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods for the proper way to structure jQuery plugins and how to define methods that can be called in your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have already went through http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods and can use the methods as mentioned there. What I was looking after is that can I wrap those methods in a object for more structuring? I am thinking on these lines as I need to know if my plugin has already been initialized or not, for which I am using jQuery.data API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the prototype method. As referred to in the docs for [authoring JQuery plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) you return an instance of the plugin object. Assuming your plugin object is custom, it is not required that you use the prototype method.

With that said, your update function would be accessible when you initialized your plugin which is where you can bind to the window resize event (assuming you want your plugin to always update when window resizes):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  //if not a local function, then you can use $this.update()
   update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

data jquery saves the object created so you can use it to call the prototype functions like this

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 $('element_selector_here').data('my').update();
}
```